# Toad development suite installation 9.7.2 commercial time taken?

Tags: installation, toad, oracle9i

I am installing Toad dev suite for oracle 9.7.2 and the screen is stuck on 'preparing configuration files, it may take several minutes.' Its been more than 45 minutes and the screen is still there. I dont know if the installation is going on or its just stuck.

I have to test something with several versions of Toad and if it takes more than an hour for 1 screen then my whole day will be wasted.

Has any one done this installation ? and how much time does this screen take ?

Comment: That's entirely too long. It takes about 1-2 mins tops for me. What installation options are you trying? If you're trying to install other programs in the bundle (i.e. not only Toad) have you tried just installing Toad?

Comment: The installer you're using is a bootstrap installer that calls the individual msis for each product. You may have success taking it out of the equation by extracting the msis individually and installing each that you want on your own. Run the installer at the command prompt with the /extract option. Select the products you're interested in and extract. Then run each msi on its own. The bootstrap installer does nothing magical that you're missing out on by doing it manually.

Comment: Hi Michael, the problem was an earlier version of toad was already installed. I dont know why there was no error and why the preparing config files screen appeared hung. But after uninstalling the old version the installation went perfectly. Thanks for the input